# Find the inorder traversal from its preorder traversal sequence in binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, sequence, traversal

I've given only a pre-order traversal sequence of a binary tree (e.g. {a, b, d, c, e}) and the task is to find out the in-order sequence from it. Pls pardon me if this is a duplicate question.... thanks

Comment: Just to make a note here, if the tree is a binary search tree with numeric key values then I know that the in-order traversal sequence is the sorted sequence of a given pre-order or post-order traversal sequence. But I was wondering what if the tree is not a BST only a BT with only alphabetical labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can find out the inorder traversal based on just the preorder traversal for a binary tree. As you said for binary search tree, sorting will give you the inorder traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a function in Python to get preorder traversal from postorder traversal. Maybe that will help you out hopefully.

For example,

If you input postorder like that
**Enter post-order traversal: ACEDBHIGF**

The preorder will be
**The pre-order traversal is GAECFTJOLP**

The inorder will be
**The in-order traversal is ABCDEFGHI**

```
def from_post_order(post_order_items, order_type="pre"):
    bst = BinarySearchTree()
    values = [item for item in post_order_items]
    root = values[-1]  # the last item in the post_order item is ROOT
    bst.insert(root)  # insert ROOT
    values.pop(-1)  # and remove it from post_order_items

    left_child = []  # the left child of ROOT for Post-order
    right_child = []  # the right child of ROOT for Post-order
    for v in values:
        if v > root:
            right_child.append(v)
        else:
            left_child.append(v)

    for i in range(len(left_child + right_child)):
        if len(left_child) != 0:
            bst.insert(left_child[-1])  # insert left child
            left_child.pop(-1)  # remove the inserted left child from the list

        if len(right_child) != 0:
            bst.insert(right_child[-1])  # insert right child
            right_child.pop(-1)  # remove the inserted right child from the list

    if order_type == "pre":
        print("The pre-order traversal is ")
        bst.preorder(print)
    elif order_type == "in":
        print("The in-order traversal is ")
        bst.inorder(print)
    else:
        print("The post-order traversal is ")
        bst.postorder(print)
```